# Is there a Vim-like word processor?

Tags: vim, word-processing

I've realized that Vim makes some basic tasks very efficient (cutting, deleting, pasting...) I would love to have those features in a word processor. Does anyone know one (I prefer open source).

Comment: What are you looking for in a word processor? I use vim to write all sorts of things, including letters and fiction, and worry about formatting later. (I just print out letters as I typed them, usually.)

Without knowing exactly what you want in the way of features, it's hard to recommend anything.

Comment: what is the problem with vim that you need a vim-like word processor? it's available for most platforms..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could edit [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) files, with Vim. That would allow you to have more formatting possibilities, while keeping the editing power of Vi. It won't give you a WYSIWYG aspect, though.

It seems that there is an open-source project to make Vim dedicated to editing LaTeX with a plugin: [Vim-LaTeX](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/). You could look into that, if interested.

Comment: In a similar vein you could edit roff/troff/groff files.  The idea is the same just the mark-up language is different.

Comment: @Gnoupi: vim-latex is a plugin, loadable in any standard `vim` installation.

Answer (score 3):

Abiword has a way to enable vi keybindings.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have Vim emulation in word, outlook, sql server and visual studio then you can use viemu (www.viemu.com). I have bought it and thoroughly recommend it. I love it....

Answer (score 1):

[seanyeh on GitHub](https://github.com/seanyeh) wrote a plugin for Open Office/LibreOffice plugin called [vibreoffice.](https://github.com/seanyeh/vibreoffice) It doesn't currently have all the features of vim itself but it has most of the basic keybindings. It's open source so you can add your own too!  Download the `.oxt` file in the dist directory and save it on your hard disk.

Open LibreOffice and go to Tools -> Extension Manager. Click "Add" and browse to the location of the `.oxt` file you downloaded earlier. After you've installed the extension use Tools -> Addons -> vibreoffice to enable the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I second the suggestion to use the Txtfmt plugin, which provides RTF-style highlighting for text documents in Vim. The plugin is highly configurable: color configuration, customizable mappings, complex user-map definitions, etc..., with carefully chosen defaults that are suitable for most users right out of the box.

Txtfmt (The Vim Highlighter)
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2208

Comment: Hello, welcome to Super User. Please check the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq) to learn more about the way this site works. If you want to "second" an answer, you should do so by voting for the answer. As explained in the FAQ, voting requires 15 of reputation. Besides, enjoy your stay in here, you can modify your account to have a name nicer than "user35341"

Answer (score -1):

Well, word processor in [Open Office](http://www.openoffice.org/) (which is both free and open source) has all the functions you mentioned: cut/copy/paste/delete.

---

[TxtFmt](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2208) - (The Vim Highlighter) : "Rich text" highlighting in Vim! (colors, underline, bold, italic, etc...)

[image]

Comment: I think he means that Vim does basic tasks like cut, copy, paste, delete in a very efficient way (with the keyboard commands). And as such, is asking for something which would be to edit like Vim, but with the possibilities of text formatting of a regular word processor like Open Office.

Comment: But Open Office does not have anything that looks like Vim keybindings.

Comment: @Gnoupi - Yes, I know. But I don't read minds, and the way question was stated, it demanded an open office with "basic tasks". Besides, you can do all of the above with the keyboard; you don't need a mouse to copy/paste. So what's he complaining about ? ;) The thing he really wants is probably txtfmt. That's as close as you're gonna get to formatting text within vim.

Comment: @Idigas - Yes, I agree it could be misleading. For the records, I didn't downvote you. Nice suggestion with this TxtFmt, that's probably the best you can do in formatting with Vim without using a markup language. +1

Comment: @Gnoupi - Oh, even if you did, I don't mind the downvote, when there is a reason. And my first answer was a little "wise". The thing I don' tunderstand is why is this still getting downvoted(?!). Eh, go figure ... ;)